# Duality gap calculation in Scikit-learn implementation of Lasso

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso, regularization, convex

I am writing a custom variation of Lasso regression, using sklearn's Lasso implementation as a "source of inspiration". And I don't quite understand the very last line in the calculation of the Lasso duality gap in sklearn.

The Lasso primal problem is ${\bf w^*} = \arg \min \limits_{\bf w} \|{\bf y} - X{\bf w}\|_2^2 + \alpha \|{\bf w}\|_1$.

The Lasso dual problem is ${\bf u^*} = \arg \min \limits_{\bf u} \| {\bf y} - {\bf u} \|_2^2$ subject to $\|X^Tu\|_\infty \le \alpha$.

Where $X {\bf w^*} = {\bf y} - {\bf u^*}$.

And [sklearn codebase](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_cd_fast.pyx#L96) mostly follows this logic. However, the calculation of the duality gap in the very last line is different from what I would expect:

```
            if (w_max == 0.0 or
            d_w_max / w_max < d_w_tol or
            n_iter == max_iter - 1):
            # the biggest coordinate update of this iteration was smaller
            # than the tolerance: check the duality gap as ultimate
            # stopping criterion

            # XtA = np.dot(X.T, R) - beta * w
            _copy(n_features, &w[0], 1, &XtA[0], 1)
            _gemv(ColMajor, Trans,
                  n_samples, n_features, 1.0, &X[0, 0], n_samples,
                  &R[0], 1,
                  -beta, &XtA[0], 1)

            if positive:
                dual_norm_XtA = max(n_features, &XtA[0])
            else:
                dual_norm_XtA = abs_max(n_features, &XtA[0])

            # R_norm2 = np.dot(R, R)
            R_norm2 = _dot(n_samples, &R[0], 1, &R[0], 1)

            # w_norm2 = np.dot(w, w)
            w_norm2 = _dot(n_features, &w[0], 1, &w[0], 1)

            if (dual_norm_XtA > alpha):
                const = alpha / dual_norm_XtA
                A_norm2 = R_norm2 * (const ** 2)
                gap = 0.5 * (R_norm2 + A_norm2)
            else:
                const = 1.0
                gap = R_norm2

            l1_norm = _asum(n_features, &w[0], 1)

            # np.dot(R.T, y)
            gap += (alpha * l1_norm
                    - const * _dot(n_samples, &R[0], 1, &y[0], 1)
                    + 0.5 * beta * (1 + const ** 2) * (w_norm2))
```

Let us ignore everything related to elastic net $\beta$ in this code and ignore Cython optimisations (luckily python/numpy code is kept in the comments).

What this code does, basically, is it calculates the residue vector R = ${\bf y} - X {\bf w}^*$, which corresponds to $\bf u^*$, then it takes $X^T {\bf u}^*$ and calculates its  infinity-norm, calling the result `dual_norm_XtA`.

Now, consider the case everything is fine and `dual_norm_XtA` < $\alpha$.

In this case I would expect the duality gap to be:

`gap` = $\underbrace{\|{\bf y} - X{\bf w}\|_2^2 + \alpha \|{\bf w}\|_1}_\text{primal} - \underbrace{\|{\bf y} - {\bf u}^*\|_2^2}_\text{dual} = \|{\bf y} - X{\bf w}\|_2^2 + \alpha \|{\bf w}\|_1 - \| X {\bf w^*} \|_2^2$

What we see instead is very similar:

```
        gap = R_norm2
        ...
        # np.dot(R.T, y)
        gap += (alpha * l1_norm
                - const * _dot(n_samples, &R[0], 1, &y[0], 1)
                + 0.5 * beta * (1 + const ** 2) * (w_norm2))
```

So, we have:

`gap` = $\|{\bf y} - X{\bf w}\|_2^2 + \alpha \|{\bf w}\|_1 - <\text{something}>$,

As `<something>` I would expect:

`np.dot(np.dot(X, w), np.dot(X, w))`, which is $\langle Xw, Xw \rangle$,

but instead, we get:

`np.dot(R.T, y)`, which is $\langle y - Xw, y \rangle$

I must be wrong somewhere, but cannot find the mistake.

---

References:

- [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/18-dual-uses.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eggordon/10725-F12/slides/18-dual-uses.pdf) - slides by Ryan Tibshirani et al.
- [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/statml/lectures/sparsity.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/statml/lectures/sparsity.pdf) - text by Ryan Tibshirani et al.